# Select only minified files with gulp and 'main-bower-files'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower

I tried to create gulp task which creates "index.html" file with bower_components included.
However, I need to include only minified bower_componets files to the index.html file.

```
 var buildVendors = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles()).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildBower));
 return gulp.src(paths.index)
.pipe(inject(buildBowerFiles,{
            relative: true,
            name: 'bowerInject'
        }));
```

Currently, I getting all the js files but not minified version of it.

```
<script src="bower/ngBootbox.js"></script>
```

I would like if it came as

```
<script src="bower/ngBootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mainBowerFiles()` function accepts a `filter` which you could use to only get the `min.js` files.

```
mainBowerFiles('**/*.min.js')
```

so your Gulp script would be

```
var buildVendors = gulp.src(mainBowerFiles('**/*.min.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildBower));
     return gulp.src(paths.index)
     .pipe(inject(buildBowerFiles,{
        relative: true,
        name: 'bowerInject'
     }));
```

That said, you could import the non-minified files and minify your compiled JS files in Gulp too.

Comment: It is working . But the problem is all bower components not getting included. some files are missing. However , those components also have min files in it.

Comment: Can you share your bower.json file? Which files aren't being included?

Comment: Yes, sure. Your script is good . But the thing is most of bower components which are having min files do not include to index file. Which means If I use  your code , I only get 3 inclusions. Without your code, I got All bower components included but all are not min.js files.

Comment: So you want both `min.js` and `.js` when the min isn't available?

Comment: min file and .js files are available in every bower components. But Code only include .js files from some components. Actually I need only .min.js files from every components.

Comment: The filter I provided should include every, and only, `min.js` files within the Bower directory.

Comment: Yes after I put your filter it only includes some of `.min.js` files. But all bower components have `.min.js` files which are not included.